# Django, PIP, and Virtualenv

Tags: python, django, setup-project, virtualenv, pip

Got this django project that I assume would run on virtualenv. I installed virtualenv through pip install and created the env but when I try to feed the pip requirements file, I got this:

```
Directory 'tagging' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
Storing complete log in /Users/XXXX/.pip/pip.log
```

Here's the entry on the log file:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/Users/XXXX/Sites/SampleProject/bin/pip run on Wed Jul 21 06:35:02 2010
Directory 'tagging' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXXX/Sites/SampleProject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 120, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/XXXX/Sites/SampleProject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.6.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 158, in run
    for req in parse_requirements(filename, finder=finder, options=options):
  File "/Users/XXXX/Sites/SampleProject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 1395, in parse_requirements
    req = InstallRequirement.from_line(line, comes_from)
  File "/Users/XXXX/Sites/SampleProject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 87, in from_line
    % name)
InstallationError: Directory 'tagging' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
```

Also, here's the requirements file I'm trying to feed:

```
# to use:
# mkvirtualenv %PROJECT% (or workon %PROJECT%)
# export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true
# pip install -r requirements.txt

# you'll also need:
# mongodb1.1.4
# imagemagick > 6.3.8 


# -e svn+http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk#egg=djangoipython
ipdb
PIL
django-extensions
django-debug-toolbar
pytz
tagging
```

Could it be a problem with PIP? I have installed it through easy_install and used it already to install some modules such as fabric and etc. with no problems.

Hope someone could lend a hand :) BTW, here's my local setup: OSX 10.6.4, Python 2.6.1, Django 1.3 alpha. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a tagging/ directory in the directory from which you are running pip, and pip thinks this directory (rather than the django-tagging project on PyPI) is what you want it to install. But there's no setup.py in that directory, so pip doesn't know how to install it.

If the name of the project you wanted to install from PyPI were actually "tagging", you'd need to move or rename the tagging/ directory, or else run pip from a different directory. But it's not; it's actually django-tagging: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tagging  So if you just change the entry in your requirements file from "tagging" to "django-tagging," it should work.

All of this is a bug in pip, really: it should assume something is a PyPI project name rather than a local directory, unless the name you give has an actual slash in it or appended to it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you've copied the "tagging" directory from this [location](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/source/browse/#svn/trunk/tagging) in the django-tagging source?  In that case, you actually need the root from this [location](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/source/browse/#svn/trunk)  which has "tagging" as a sub-directory and a setup.py file.  Just checkout from trunk or unzip to a "django-tagging" directory and make sure that your requirements file points to the "django-tagging" directory.